# Questions about options in http settings "overide host name" and "pick host name from backend address"

Tags: http, settings, azure-application-gateway

I did some test for http settings options "overide host name" and "pick host name from backend address", but got a little confused as the result was different for different type of backend pools.

APPGW: test.cloudapp.net

Backend pool1: VM1(IP1) (azure vm in same virtual network with APPGW); frontend url: test.cloudapp.net:8081

Backend pool2: FQDN - test.azurewebsites.net(azure web app); frontend url: test.cloudapp.net:8082

(1) test for option "override host name"
For both 2 backend pools, set the value of option "override host name" in http settings to "test.azurewebsites.net" which is the FQDN of backend pool2.

Try to access url test.cloudapp.net:8081 and test.cloudapp.net:8082, I thought it should return the same result from test.azurewebsites.net. But the result was that: 
For test.cloudapp.net:8082, it returned content of test.azurewebsites.net which was expected.
But for test.cloudapp.net:8081, it returned content on VM1. My question is that why it didn't return the content of test.azurewebsites.net.

(2) test for option "pick host name from backend address"
When this option was disabled by default, I can't visit url test.cloudapp.net:8082 while test.cloudapp.net:8081 was accessable with correct result.
When this option was enabled, both url test.cloudapp.net:8081 and test.cloudapp.net:8082 were accessable with correct result.
My question is: When this option is disabled, what's the host name in http header when APPGW send http request packet to backend pool1 and backend pool2?
When this option is enabled, I think the host name in http packet sent to backend pool1 should be IP1 and to backend pool2 should be "test.azurewebsites.net", but not sure.

Really appreciate if someone could provide detailed explanation for my test result and confusion.

Comment: Can you please share more details on the following ?  Application gateway configs. How many listeners with name , How many backend pool with name, how many HTTPSettings with name , also rule configurations. Are you using HTTPS in the HTTPS settings ?

Comment: @msrini-MSIT Two listeners: listener1- HTTP, port 8081; listener2 -HTTP, port 8082. Two backend pools: pool1-VM; pool2-FQDN test.azurewebsites.net.  Two http settings: basicly default configuration are used(HTTP, port 80) except "override host name" and "pick host name from backend address" which are used to test. Two rules are simple: listener1-pool1-httpsettings1 like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select "Override hostname" settings, Application gateway will set the hostname header in the HTTP to whatever hostname you set.

For example, when you browse http://40.x.x.x which is the IP of your Application gateway, without http override, when the packet reaches the backend resource, the request will have hostname as 40.x.x.x (The hostname with which you browsed the site) and if the backend is a web app, it expects the hostname field as xxxx.azurewebsites.net. As this request has ip in the hostname, your web app will throw 404.

In order to overcome this issue, you can either choose "pick hostname from backend address pool" and specify your web app FQDN as backend pool or you can override the hostname in HTTP settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like I have misunderstood the usage of these two options. Thanks so much.